# An easy real life scenario that Neo4j can handle faster than MySQL

Tags: mysql, neo4j

I'll have a talk about Neo4j and I want to show 1 scenario that Neo4j can handle faster than MySQL.

I created random data and SQL-tables for a "social network" like Twitter:
There are 1,000,000 persons and each of them follows 50 other persons.
So there are 2 tables "person" and "following":

Is there a Cypher-query that is a lot faster than the MySQL query that should do the same?

I tried sth like "friend of a friend of a fried" scenarios but MySQL solves them fast...

Comment: That sucks, when you want to prove that X is better than Y and while demonstrating it, you show that Y is better than X.

Comment: I want to show that Neo4j is better in handling special GRAPH/NETWORK/HIERARCHY-scenarios. I don't want to show that it's better at all...

Comment: I believe the last sentence of your comment is missing the word "scenarios" at the end. And @Cid probably did not mean that neo4j is better at everything. [Not even neo4j claims that](https://sdtimes.com/databases/guest-view-relational-vs-graph-databases-use/). That linked article may also be helpful with your talk.

Answer (score 5):

One scenario that's harder for rdbms is when the types of the nodes (tables) to traverse aren't known. Take a graph that has :Person nodes different connections through different types of nodes (:Workplace, :Organization, :School, etc) and you need a query that might be doing a reachability query at a distance between two known nodes (are these nodes connected through any means, or through some means using some subset of labels and relationship types?), or doing a 7 degrees from Kevin Bacon query or something similar.

When you write these kinds of queries, you have minimal information about the nodes to traverse through, you want to know if and how they are connected, you do not know the exact manner of this connection ahead of time. How do you write that in SQL? You would usually need to know ahead of time the join tables to use and the intermediate tables along the way (especially if you have to do property filtering on some of the intermediate nodes).

Or how about cases where you can treat nodes with some degree of generality, yet use variable-length relationships to still get what you want?

For example, if you have :Place nodes that have :IN_LOCATION relationships, where those relationships can either point to :Address, :City, :State, or :Country depending on what the place is and how accurate your data, and those nodes themselves have :WITHIN relationships between them, you might try getting the state information like this:

```
MATCH (p:Place {name:'Yosemite National Park'})-[:IN_LOCATION]->()-[:WITHIN*0..]->(state:State)
RETURN state
```

In this query, you don't know the label (type) of the left-blank node the :IN_LOCATION relationship points to. However you know that if it's at the :State level or below, you want to keep traversing :WITHIN relationships until you reach a :State node (possibly traversing none at all if that initial node is a :State node), without caring about the types of the intermediate nodes.

Is that something that SQL can do?

Plus there are whole classes of graph algorithms and use cases that are hard to do, sometimes impossible to do, with SQL as you often don't care much about the multiple types of nodes to traverse. This includes things like shortestPath algorithms, reachability queries, closest x nodes of certain types, etc.

There's also cases of getting all connected nodes in a subgraph, whether that's unrestricted, or only subgraphs reachable through certain relationships, or only comprised of certain nodes (or excepting certain nodes). Something like this:

```
MATCH (k:Person{name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED*..5]-(m:Movie)
RETURN collect(DISTINCT m) as movies
```